# ionic start project connection error (ERRCONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, proxy, npm

I have this error when I try to start a new ionic project.

Note:I may have mucked around with proxies at work at some point (behind a proxy), and now it is showing this error at home (direct connection).  I'm not sure if this is an issue with proxies for sure though.

The Error:

Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Users\sam\hiya based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error Initializing app: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:176:17)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:267:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)

tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 (CLI v1.7.16)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.5

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Sam

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change your default ionicServeAddress on ionic.config file. 
On Mac this file is at ~/.ionic. On a PC it can be found at C:/users/username/.ionic. Inside you'll see something like

> "ionicServeAddress": "localhost"

Perhaps changing to your proxies ip or localhost might help.